# detect what is the phone via the browser

Tags: android, ios, hyperlink, sms

I will be sending SMS to my clients to download my app.
In the sms I want to place a link, which when opened on the device, checks whether the device has iOS and automatically takes to app store, if it is running android, it takes to the google play.

How to achieve this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Get the user agent string and check of 'Apple' or 'Android'. Android has the following pattern:

> ```
> Phone pattern: 'Android' + 'Chrome/[.0-9]* Mobile'
> Tablet pattern: 'Android' + 'Chrome/[.0-9]* (?!Mobile)'
> ```

Apple appears to have the works 'Apple' and 'iPhone' in all user agent strings.

[Apple User Agent Strings](http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Complete_List_of_iOS_User_Agent_Strings)

[Android User Agent Strings](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent)

**Edit**

Assuming you want to do this in Javascript, have the the link navigate to an html page. In the head add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1){
            window.location.href = 'linkToPlayStore';
        }else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1){
            window.location.href = 'linkToApStore';
        }
    }
</javascript>
```

Comment: can you not speak chinese ?

Comment: now we're talking. thx for the edit. where should I add the links of the appstore and google play ?

Comment: What does not work? The navigation to URL or the user string connection?